# External monitor doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, display, dell, intel

I've got new laptop recently - Dell 5531. It has Intel integrated GPU and Nvidia MX550. I am trying to connect external monitor, tried 3 options:

1. Using Dell dock (TB16) and thunderbolt port -  which is working fine with older laptop, Dell 5591 - ethernet and audio are detected correctly in the system, but display is not.
2. Connecting directly to HDMI port to laptop - cable is detected but no signal on external monitor.
3. Connecting directly to thunderbolt port on the laptop and HDMI in the monitor - in this case monitor doesn't even detect the connection.

I am using "on demand" mode in Nvidia setup. I know my ports in laptop are wired to Intel card. Any ideas what can I do?

Comment: Do not use "on demand". Select Nvidia profile and reboot. Test ports.

Comment: I've tried that of course. It didn't help - no matter the selected profile, it doesn't work. I also got information from Nvidia forums that all external ports are wired to the Intel integrated GPU, not Nvidia MX550, so "on demand" should be fine. I am currently in the process of checking what the issue may be with Dell tech support, let's see...

Answer (score 1):

The specifications for the Lattitude 5591 indicate that it has VGA, HDMI, and optional displayport over USB C (thunderbolt).   The third option may have bios settings to enable and disable it.

There have been multiple standards for displayport over USB C / thunderbolt, so if your docking station was targeted at an older laptop, it may not have the correct interface to get video from the new laptop, despite the fact that the cables might fit in the holes.

Assuming that all these ports are enabled in bios and you actually have the optional hardware in the laptop to support them, you still need the correct video drivers in the operating system.  If you are lucky, the command `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` may find the right drivers and install them.  (Reboot may be required.)

If that doesn't work, Dell does list the Lattitude 5591 as supporting linux, so you may be able to download the correct drivers from Dell's website.  However, Dell lists Ubuntu 18 as supported, so I would expect the drivers to be built into Ubuntu 22 (in which case, the command above should find them).

The Lattitude 5531 specifications only list a single HDMI video out.  It doesn't mention video over USB C, so likely your dock won't work with video on it.  Dell's website indicate Ubuntu 20 is supported, so again, it is likely Ubuntu 22 includes the drivers.  However, Dell also shows a critical bios update for this system, so that may be necessary for the video to work correctly if you haven't already applied it.  Be sure to try  `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and see if the drivers are found.  If for some reason, Dell's Ubuntu 20 drivers were not integrated into Ubuntu 22, you may need to wait for Dell to release new drivers.

Comment: I'm sorry - the new laptop is 5531, the older one is 5591, I edited my question. About the drivers, I installed them, the newest version of nvidia drivers available is 515 and this is the one I have. Everything is also enabled in BIOS. I understand that docking station may not work as it's quite old comparing to the laptop. Direct connection will also be good, either by HDMI or display port to HDMI. Unfortunately none of this works. xrandr shows ports are disconnected while they are not. No issues with cables or monitors as they all work on different laptop with Windows.

Comment: Minor nit pick:  It's not a Dell 5531 or Dell 5591.   It's a Dell Lattitude 5531, Lattitude 5591.  Sometimes that matters, they sometimes reuse the same number in different lines.

Comment: Yes,it's Latitude series, you're right. I asked Dell for the help today, let's see what they say.